# Is there a safe way to shutdown Jetson Nano (Linux) from C++ without sudo permissions?

Tags: c++, linux, sudo, shutdown

I know the question sounds odd but what I'm trying to do is create a C++ program for the Jetson Nano that should run automatically at startup and when finished shut down the system. Since it's autostarted, I cannot specify a sudo password, threrefore I need a way to do it without, e.g. by giving execute permissions to shutdown scripts or whatever. If you know a better solution, feel free to share, I would be very happy about any hints.

The second problem is that I can't find a C++ command to shut down the Linux based Jetson Nano safely. I tried 2 different solutions:

```
int (main) {
    system("/bin/sh -c shutdown -P now");
}
```

After doing this 2 times, the system on startup got stuck in a login loop, so my whole OS got trashed. I had to reinstall to another SD card.

```
int (main) {
    reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF);
}
```

This also works, but it shuts down the Jetson Nano kind of harshly, the kernel messages normally shown at shutdown don't display. Since I don't want to risk another system failure, can anyone suggest an approved and safe method to shut down the Jetson Nano?
Thanks!

Comment: If it's a permissions thing, try using the system's scheduler.  I know systemd's tie in for shutdown works from a non-root use (this is how a regular user shuts down the machine).  A sloppier alternative is to make your own "run as root" executable via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79692/running-program-as-root-without-using-sudo-with-normal-user-account

Comment: Hey, thanks for suggesting. I don't have much Linux experience, so I don't know what a system scheduler is. Can you please link me specific instructions how to achieve the described things? Thanks!

Comment: `shutdown` without `now` doesn't need root permissions but it will wait for a minute.